# Sorting the model table with Sequelize in Node.js

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have the query of Sequelize which I connected 2 tables as following:

```
        await Task.findOne({
            where: { id: 5 },
            include: [
                {
                    model: Video,
                    attributes:['id'],
                    order: [
                        [
                            {model: Video, as: 'video'},
                            'id',
                            'ASC'
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
        })
```

I get the results from here but I want the results of the video table to come sorted by video's id. My order is not working in this query

Comment: I am assuming Task and Video both have "id" attribute? Can you paste a sample object

Comment: @arpit, imagine Task table has ['id', 'name', 'angle', ...] columns and Video table has ['id', 'task_id', 'path'] colmuns. So every task has many videos. They are associated to each other and it works fine but I only want the videos to be sorted according to their id.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if the `order` is in the main table, not the included table.

Try like this:

```
await Task.findOne({
        where: { id: 5 },
        include: [
            {
                model: Video,
                attributes:['id'],
                
            }
        ],
        order : [[Video,'id']]         
    })
```

Alternatively, you could find on Video and include Task.

Comment: Its not working and giving this error : "error": "Unable to find a valid association for model, 'Video'.

Comment: Video is already associated and works without sorting.

Comment: can you post your association from Task to Video?  I tested my proposed answer and it works fine.